# mobile detection between 2 different platforms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am in the process of wrapping up a mobile site and I need to give the user the option to switch from the mobile(jQuery mobile) site to the desktop version of the site.  I am planning on using the code below for detection on both sides and then setting a cookie if the user makes the preference of one or the other site (mobile / desktop).  I am curious to know best practice for this type of thing as I feel this will work well but not sure if there is a better way.

```
var isMobile = navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') > -1
```

Thanks in advance,

JN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it but because there are so many variations of user agents it can definitely be tricky. However, there is a nice script out there that solves this problem fairly elegantly. It also handles the cookie'ing that you touched on as well.

https://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. (sorry for delayed acceptance)